# Replacing sections of 2D array with a smaller 2D array using masks

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, masking

How can I replace multiple instances of a pattern in a large 2D numpy array with a smaller 2D numpy array?

I am looking for a vectorized solution using a boolean mask to minimize the performance impact because the large array I'm working will be millions of rows long.

For example:

```
#Large array
largeArr = np.array([
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
])
```

I would like to replace sections with 3 consecutive rows containing `[0, 1, 1]` with

```
pattern1 = [
    [0, 2, 1],
    [0, 2, 2],
    [0, 2, 3]
]
```

Then I would like to replace sections with 4 consecutive rows containing `[3, 2, 0]` with

```
pattern2 = [
    [5, 2, 1],
    [5, 3, 2],
    [5, 4, 3],
    [5, 5, 4]
]
```

Expected result:

```
[[0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [5, 2, 1],
 [5, 3, 2],
 [5, 4, 3],
 [5, 5, 4],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [5, 2, 1],
 [5, 3, 2],
 [5, 4, 3],
 [5, 5, 4],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

There will be multiple patterns to find and replace, each with their own replacement array. The intent is to loop over the provided search rows and replacement patterns one at a time.

The search row is always a single row, repeated as many times as there are rows in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Does your large array only contain `[0,0,0]` and `[0,1,1]` in blocks of three?

Comment: No, it will contain any combination of integers. The solution will be used to replace multiple patterns within a loop

Comment: Can you guarantee that patterns do not overlap?

Comment: There will be alternating patterns, but I will loop through the array and replace each pattern throughout the array

Comment: Are search patterns always one row repeated N times?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Please post your arrays as pastable code. I.e. `large_array = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], ... [3, 3, 3]]` rather than just `[[1, 1, 1] [2, 2, 2] ... [3, 3, 3]]`. Variable names and commas are helpful to build understanding. Format your comments with a `#`

Comment: There you go, should be good now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll have an answer in a few minutes. It's a simple but non-trivial transformation.

Comment: Thank you @MadPhysicist, I appreciate you using your time to help. Previously, I had iterated through each row in the large array which decreased performance by an ungodly amount. A vectorized solution will be so helpful but I've been struggling with it so again, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Enjoy. I use the method I show you here quite often. It looks long, but totally vectorized and very fast. An array with 11 million rows and 6 replacement patterns ran in < 3 sec on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that all your quantities are arrays, not lists. If that's not the case, wrap them in `np.array`:

```
search = np.array([0, 1, 1])
pattern = np.array(pattern1)
```

The size of a block is given by

```
n = len(pattern)  # or pattern.shape[0]
```

I assume that you want to replace only non-overlapping segments. So while six rows of `search` make for exactly two instances of `pattern` in the output, seven rows make for two instances of `pattern` and an instance of `search`.

Searching for a pattern is simple. Start by creating a mask of where rows match the pattern:

```
mask = (largeArr == search).all(1)
```

The idiom for finding contiguous runs of a mask has been beaten to death on this site. The gist is to use `np.diff` to find where the sign of the mask changes, then `np.flatnonzero` to get indices, and `np.diff` again to compute run lengths.  First pad the mask to ensure that the result includes endpoints correctly:

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[False, mask, False])).reshape(-1, 2)
runs = np.diff(indices, axis=1).squeeze()
```

Notice that `indices` has been reshaped to two columns for convenience. The passing l padding guarantees that this is possible. The first column is the start of each run (inclusive), while the second is the end (exclusive). That makes computing the run lengths in `runs` trivial.

Now you can adjust `indices` to include only runs of size `n` or longer, and trim the ending elements to be a multiple of `n` away from the start elements:

```
# runs = n * (runs // n), but for huge arrays
np.floor_divide(runs, n, out=runs)
np.multiply(runs, n, out=runs)

indices[:, 1] = indices[:, 0] + runs
```

You could trim zero-length runs out of `indices` using `indices = indices[np.flatnonzero(runs)]`, but this is not necessary. The next step is to convert the adjusted `indices` back into a mask:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=np.int8)
```

The `np.uint8` dtype allows you to store +1 and -1 in the mask, and is the same size as `np.bool_`, which means that if done properly, the final result can be seamlessly viewed as a boolean mask:

```
starts, ends = indices.T
if ends[-1] == mask.size:
    ends = ends[:-1]
mask[starts] = 1
mask[ends] -= 1  # This takes care of zero-length segments automatically
mask = np.cumsum(mask, out=mask).view(bool)
```

The extra processing for `ends`, which is unpacked as the second column of `indices`, takes care of the case where the mask runs to the end of the array. Since end indices are exclusive, this would be past the end of the array, but that also means that that run does not need to be terminated at all.

Now that your mask has been filtered and trimmed, you can assign to the correct rows in `largeArr`. The simplest way is to repeat `pattern` as many times as necessary:

```
largeArr[mask, :] = np.tile(pattern, [runs.sum() // n, 1])
```

If you package this into a function, you can run it for multiple patterns:

```
def replace_pattern(arr, search, pattern):
    n = len(pattern)
    mask = (arr == search).all(1)
    indices = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[False, mask, False])).reshape(-1, 2)
    runs = np.diff(indices, axis=1).squeeze()
    np.floor_divide(runs, n, out=runs)
    np.multiply(runs, n, out=runs)
    indices[:, 1] = indices[:, 0] + runs
    mask = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=np.int8)
    starts, ends = indices.T
    if ends[-1] == mask.size:
        ends = ends[:-1]
    mask[starts] = 1
    mask[ends] -= 1
    mask = np.cumsum(mask, out=mask).view(bool)
    arr[mask, :] = np.tile(pattern, [runs.sum() // n, 1])

replacements = [
    ([0, 1, 1], [[0, 2, 1],
                 [0, 2, 2],
                 [0, 2, 3]]),
    ([3, 2, 0], [[5, 2, 1],
                 [5, 3, 2],
                 [5, 4, 3],
                 [5, 5, 4]])
]

largeArr = np.array(...)

for search, pattern in replacements:
    replace_pattern(largeArr, search, pattern)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I will add this to my project tonight and let you know how it goes. You're a godsend.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it works out for you. This was an entertaining puzzle

Comment: Everything is working great, except on the final replacement pattern  I'm getting `Exception has occurred: IndexError index 1323 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1323` on the line with `mask[indices[:, 1]] -= 1`. Any ideas?

Comment: @CraigNathan. Yeah. I forgot about that. When the mask runs all the way to the end it requires special treatment. Will add fix soon

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I guess I don't fully understand what those lines are doing - the taking care of zero-length segments. Do I need this if I know in advance that the lengths of all the runs to be replaced will be the length of their replacement array?

Comment: @CraigNathan. This corner case gets me every time. Thanks for the catch. I've added the fix

Comment: @CraigNathan. This code doesn't really do anything special to the runs. The only part you can get rid of is the three lines `np.floor_divide...; np.multiply...; np.indices[....`. They're the only place that incomplete runs and multiple runs are addressed. The overhead is so small, I'd recommend keeping it in and maybe even printing a message if those lines actually do something, because that implies that your data is not what you're expecting.

Comment: @CraigNathan. Try to make a pattern of length 3, but with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 repetitions of the search row

Comment: Works like a charm. I have patterns of length 3 with 3 and 9 repetitions of the search row and it works great. Thank you!

Comment: I posted another related question if your interested. It's regarding how to vectorize the creation of largeArr in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636478/python-numpy-vectorizing-row-insertion-in-a-2d-array