# Python/Numpy: Vectorizing repeated row insertion in a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, masking

Is it possible to vectorize the insertion of rows?

I have a large 2D numpy array `arr` (below) and a list of `indices`. For each index of `arr` in `indices` I would like to insert the row at that index back into `arr` row 5 times at that same index.

```
indices = [2, 4, 5, 9, 11, 12, 16, 18, 19]
```

Currently I'm just looping through all the indices and inserting new rows. This approach is slow for a large list of thousands of rows, so for performance reasons I'm wondering is it possible to vectorize this multi-point tile-type insertion?

```
arr = [       
        [' ', ' ', 'd'],
        [' ', 'd', ' '],
        [' ', 'd', 'd'],    # <-- reinsert arr[2] here 5 times
        ['d', ' ', ' '],
        ['d', ' ', 'd'],    # <-- reinsert arr[4] here 5 times
        ['d', 'd', ' '],    # <-- reinsert arr[5] here 5 times
        ['d', 'd', 'd'],
        [' ', ' ', 'e'],
        [' ', 'e', ' '],
        [' ', 'e', 'e'],    # <-- reinsert arr[9] here 5 times
        ['e', ' ', ' '],
        ['e', ' ', 'e'],    # <-- reinsert arr[11] here 5 times
        ['e', 'e', ' '],    # <-- reinsert arr[12] here 5 times
        ['e', 'e', 'e'],
        [' ', ' ', 'f'],
        [' ', 'f', ' '],
        [' ', 'f', 'f'],    # <-- reinsert arr[16] here 5 times
        ['f', ' ', ' '],
        ['f', ' ', 'f'],    # <-- reinsert arr[18] here 5 times
        ['f', 'f', ' ']     # <-- reinsert arr[19] here 5 times
    ]
```

Example of first insertion of desired result:

```
arr = [       
        [' ', ' ', 'd'],
        [' ', 'd', ' '],
        [' ', 'd', 'd'],    # <-- arr[2]
        [' ', 'd', 'd'],    # <-- new insert
        [' ', 'd', 'd'],    # <-- new insert
        [' ', 'd', 'd'],    # <-- new insert
        [' ', 'd', 'd'],    # <-- new insert
        [' ', 'd', 'd'],    # <-- new insert
        ['d', ' ', ' ']
        #...
      ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.repeat` for this:

```
indices = [2, 4, 5, 9, 11, 12, 16, 18, 19]
rpt = np.ones(len(arr), dtype=int)
rpt[indices] = 5

np.repeat(arr, rpt, axis=0)
```

Comment: I would suggest replacing `20` with `len(arr)` here to make it clear where it comes from