# Python/Numpy: How large can a Numpy Unicode array be?

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

How large can a Numpy Unicode array be?

`dtype = 'U100', 'U1000', 'U1000000'` ?

I cannot find any reference of maximums the documentation.

Comment: Are you asking "how large can a Unicode array be?" or are you asking "what's the largest code point I can store in a Unicode type?   Numpy's Unicode type is Python's string type.  It can represent anything in Unicode. which goes up through U+10FFFF.

Comment: I think the question is "how large can *elements of* a Unicode array be?"

Comment: Either way, I’m voting to close this question because Stack overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation (and the one answer so far was found directly in the documentation, despite OP's inability to find it).

Comment: The question is "how large can a Unicode array be?" Will update the question sorry for ambiguity

Comment: `numpy` isn't great for large strings.  `nbtyes` for a `np.zeros((1000,), dtype='U500')` will be 1000*500*4, regardless of the actual strings.

Comment: The reason I use numpy is because I grow a very large array using np.tile and np.repeat which is much faster than iteratively building the array. I convert the numpy array to a dataframe before accessing any of the data.

Comment: @hpaulj How does that compare to storing in a list?

Comment: A list stores references to Python objects (stored elsewhere).  The length (bytes) of an individual string is variable, a maximum of the number of characters *4 (but I think Unicode character length can actually vary - I haven't pair attention).  Also keep in mind the `numpy` does not implement its own string manipulation methods - it relies on Python.  So `numpy` doesn't offer any speed advantages.

Comment: @hpaulj I use numpy because it allows be to vectorize the construction of a 2D array of strings which will end up containing millions of rows. Ex) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636478/python-numpy-vectorizing-repeated-row-insertion-in-a-2d-array. The string elements in this example can grow to thousands of characacters each so I was just wondering what my limit was.

Comment: Functions like `repeat` and `tile` don't change the `dtype`, nor do they depend on an `dtype` details (except for the number of bytes per element).  So they behave the same whether the dtype is numeric or 'U1000'.  But as you found in the other question, joining the elements into larger strings is best done with lists and Python strings.

Comment: @CraigNathan in which case, have you considered just using `object` dtype? It will keep references to Python objects in the actual array, with the objects being allocated on the private heap as is normal for Python objects, but it should be much more space efficient than using something like `U10000` if most of your strings are significantly smaller

Comment: It would probably help if you gave us more details about what your actual use-case is. There are a lot of trade-offs involved here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, in fact `pandas` uses object dtype instead of the `numpy` string dtypes.  It also seems to have easier access to string methods, though I haven't done any timings.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, I think they've Cythonized some vectorized string methods. And actually, `pandas` since 1.0 came out has a dedicated string dtype, which makes sense since operations on strings are a core use-case, unlike numpy.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @juanpa.arrivillaga I have 2 large arrays - `arr1` contains strings that are conditional statements and `arr2` contains an array of boolean mask arrays which correspond to where in a large dataset each conditional statement in `arr1` is true. I construct each array using np.tile and np.repeat in a way that gives me every possible combination of conditionals and mask arrays. Currently, I calculate the `longestStr` in `arr1` and use `'U' + 'longestStr'` as my dtype for `arr1`. Once the arrays are built, I add both arrays to a single pandas dataframe

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So you're saying that at some point using `object` dtype is more space efficient than `'U'+ str(n)`. Do you have any tips on how can I find out after what integer n that using `object` dtype is more space efficient?

Comment: @CraigNathan that is super complicated. Python `str` objects have a lot of overhead. It is possible to intern Python strings, however, which would make it very efficient if you have a lot of potential repeats. The runtime may intern them due to various optimizations that are arcane in nature. But generally, play around with `sys.getsize` and you should get an idea, considering you have to use *the maximum possible size* if you want a `U` dtype

Comment: Thank you very much for your direction. I will read up on interning Python strings and experiment with `sys.getsize` to see where it's more efficient to use `object` dtype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this line in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html:

> Total dtype *itemsize* is limited to `ctypes.c_int`.

Which for 32-bit signed integer would be 2,147,483,647.  But practically, the byte size of the item is also limited, so divide by 4 (Unicode code point size) is `2147483647 // 4` or 536,870,911.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(['abcdef'],dtype='U536870911')
array(['abcdef'], dtype='<U536870911')
>>> np.array(['abcdef'],dtype='U536870911').itemsize
2147483644
```

Also:

> `dtype.itemsize`
>
> The element size of this data-type object.
>
> For 18 of the 21 types this number is fixed by the data-type. For the flexible data-types, this number can be anything.

Comment: Pretty certain that isn't relevant, that section seems to be talking about specifying structured dtypes in a particular way

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Most of the dtypes are structured and fixed size (1,2,4,8,...), but Unicode strings are one of the "flexible" data types.  See update.  Note you can specify dtype as `'U10000'` or `('U',10000)` so while it talks about the latter, it implies the former as well.

Comment: I'm still not sure what it's saying exactly, I suppose it must be a *multiple* of `4`, since `np.array(['abcdefghij']).itemsize` is `40`. In any case, I'm not sure this is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's number of Unicode code points per element for `dtype`.  For the actual array it is byte size of the item.  `x=np.array(['abcdef'],dtype=('U',2))` returns `array(['ab'], dtype='<U2')` and `x.itemsize == 8`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Practically, the byte-wise itemsize overflows if the code point length is too long.  I was able to use a size of `('U',2**29-1)` before it complained (4x that is 0x7ffffffc).